# I have a question regarding the Autopy mouse toggle

Tags: python

While using the Python autopy module, I used the following code. the code is more likely to repeat the click while touching two fingers compared to what is normally realized
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m0BN.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import HandTrackingModule as htm
import time
import autopy

#######
wCam, hCam = 640, 480
frameR = 100 # Frame Reduction
smoothening = 5
#######

pTime = 0
plocX, plocY = 0,0
clocX, clocY = 0,0

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)

detector = htm.handDetector(maxHands=1)
wScr, hScr = autopy.screen.size()

while True:
# 1. Find hand Landmarks
success, img = cap.read()
img = detector.findHands(img)
lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)

# 2. Get the tip of the index and middle fingers

if len(lmList) != 0:
    x1, y1 = lmList[8][1:]
    x2, y2 = lmList[12][1:]

    #print(x1,y1,x2,y2)

    # 3. Check which fingers are up
    fingers = detector.fingersUp()
    #print(fingers)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (frameR, frameR), (wCam - frameR, hCam - frameR),
                  (255, 0, 255), 2)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbVOf.png)

    # 4. Only Index Finger : Moving Mode
    if fingers[1]==1 and fingers[2] == 1:

        # 5. Covert Coordinates
        x3 = np.interp(x2, (frameR, wCam-frameR), (0, wScr))
        y3 = np.interp(y2, (frameR, hCam-frameR), (0, hScr))

        # 6. Smoothen Values
        clocX = plocX + (x3 - plocX) / smoothening
        clocY = plocY + (y3 - plocY) / smoothening

        # 7. Move Mouse
        autopy.mouse.move(wScr-clocX, clocY)
        cv2.circle(img,(x1,y1),15,(255,0,255),cv2.FILLED )
        plocX, plocY = clocX, clocY
        length, img, lineInfo = detector.findDistance(8, 12, img)
        if length < 40:
            # 10. Click mouse if distance short
            cv2.circle(img, (lineInfo[4], lineInfo[5])
                       , 15, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            autopy.mouse.click()
    # 8. Both Index and Middle fingers are up : Clicking Mode
    #if fingers[1] == 1 and fingers[2] == 1:
        # 9. Find distance between fingers



    # 11. Frame Rate
cTime = time.time()
fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
pTime = cTime
cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (20, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
            (255, 0, 0), 3)
# 12. Display
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I tried to keep it in the form of a toggle and worked with autopy.mouse.click() in the form of autopy.mouse.toggle(True).
Then C:\Users\cocok\PycharmProjects\HandMouse\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\cocok\PycharmProjects\HandMouse\main.py
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\cocok\PycharmProjects\HandMouse\main.py", line 64, in 
autopy.mouse.toggle(True)
TypeError: Required argument ('down') (pos 2) not found
The following error message appears. There are two things we're looking forward to. fingers[1]==1 and finger[2]==1: I want the mouse to be just a click away, and the rest of the fingers[0]~fingers[4]==0 to toggle shape. I'm wondering where the problem came from and in what form it needs to be fixed. I look for the latest data, but most of them are from 4 years ago, so they don't appear.